# CPU utilization in multicore processors

Tags: operating-system

How to calculate overall CPU utilization for multicore processors mathematically? 
Given a workload that runs on 4 cores and then on 8 cores, so what is the CPU utilization in each case?

Comment: CPU utilization is simply just the ratio the time spent doing something useful vs the time the total time.  As for your second question there isn't enough data to give a meaningful answer.  But if you mean 4 cores are fully utilized on a 8 core system that is an overall 50% load on the CPU.  If that same workload is then spread across 8 cores its still 50% its just that each core is now running at 50% utilization.  Then you have to consider what it means to be busy (i.e idle vs user vs system vs interrupt vs io busy waits).